# Return C++ reference wrapper

Tags: c++, function, reference, stl, reference-wrapper

Is it dangerous to return a reference wrapper like showed below:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> foo() {

    int x = 10;

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vec;
    vec.push_back(x);
    return vec;

}

foo2() {
    std::cout << foo()[0] << std::endl;
}
```

I assume the local/stack variable x can be lost in `foo2()`.

Comment: A usual dangling pointer/reference

Answer (score 1):

Function `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> foo();` essentially returns a vector with references to local variables located in function's stack which has been destroyed. A vector of dangling references. This is undefined behaviour.